# Postgres migrations fail in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose, migration

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-server
      context: .
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - migration
    ports:
      - "50051:50051"
    entrypoint: /app/grpc-server/grpc-server
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.2
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "$POSTGRES_USER", "-d", "$POSTGRES_DB" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 10s
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 4G
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  migration:
    working_dir: /migrations
    image: migrate/migrate
    volumes:
      - ./pkg/db/postgres/migrations:/migrations
    command: [ "-path", "", "-database", "postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable", "up" ]
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Migrations fail when I'm trying to launch docker-compose. **Error: URL cannot be empty**
What url I need to write if I specified my work-dir in migration service. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it complaining about the empty `-path ''` option; do you need maybe `["-path", ".", ...]` instead?